# Address Book / Contacts.app AppleScript plugins no longer working in Mojave

Tags: applescript, contacts, mojave, plugins

For years, I've relied on an AppleScript (.scpt) file placed in `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.AddressBook` to provide click-to-dial functionality via our Asterisk PBX directly from macOS Contacts.app. Up until 10.13.6, this worked well.

Since Mojave 10.14 (also tested on 10.14.1 beta) the script's menu item no longer appear.

I've tried to inspect the running process in Activity Monitor's "Open Files & Ports" tab, thinking that maybe Apple moved the Plug-Ins folder—but that revealed nothing.

Does anyone know if this feature has been removed? Or any way restore this functionality?

I found this thread on Apple's forum (no answer yet): https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8552822

Comment: Not running macOS Mojave however, just a suggestion... As a result of changes made over the last several version of macOS I've switched to using [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to run many of my scripts I used to create Automator Services and assign hotkeys in System Preferences for. Maybe you can mod the script to accommodate being triggered using FastScripts.  **Note:** I am not affiliated with Red Sweater Software, the developer of FastScript, just a satisfied user for my particular needs.

Comment: Can you put your script into an automator service instead? I've never used application scripts, but I know for sure Automator services still work under Mojave.

Comment: With the new privacy rules under Mojave your Asterisk PBS no longer has permission to access your Contacts.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's incorrect. The Asterisk PBX never had any access to my contacts. This was an Applescript plugin that passed the contact# to the PBX using standard HTTP calls.

Comment: Could you please let us know what your Console log says at the time stamp of interest.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy No, sadly that doesn't work. Only .scpt files were designed to appear in the context menu of Contacts.

Comment: Same problem, Asterisk or Apple script plug in, the access to contacts is denied. check your log

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm a developer of some Address Book (Contacts) plugins and none of them work with Mojave. I wrote Apple's developer support last week but haven't heard back from them. Just guessing that they're unsupported due to the increased privacy controls. I didn't find any updated documentation about the issue, no release notes, and the 10.14 SDKs still contain the necessary headers and frameworks to support them so I'm not sure if it's a permanent or temporary problem.

Comment: @BrianToth Thanks for that. I guess all we can do is cross our fingers and hope Apple gets back to you. Please do come back and update if you work out a solution.

Comment: Are plugins different from Scripts? The contacts app still works fine with standard applescript (`osascript -e 'tell application "Contacts" to get first name of my card'`) and scripts (scpt files) added to `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Contacts` show up in the scripts menu. Is this question solved in 10.14.4?

Comment: @Quantum7 I think you might be referring to the systemwide "Script menu" (Script Editor > Preferences). That is not what this is about. Contacts.app used to be extensible via plugins which would add actions to the context menu of individual phone numbers. I tested again with 10.14.4 by placing my .scpt in both `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.AddressBook` as well as `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Contacts` (which did not even exist) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @luckman212 Ah, that does sound like a useful feature. Maybe the Script Menu could provide a work around though. Plugins might require some adaptation to reference the correct selection.

Comment: Do you have an example plugin code?

Answer (score 4):

I heard back from a Developer Technical Support Engineer at Apple and he said:

"I’ve asked the engineering team about this and indeed, we have removed support for both compiled and AppleScript-based AddressBook plugins in Mojave 10.14."

His suggestion was to file an enhancement request via their Bug Reporter. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Ugh. That is horrible news. "If it ain't broke, let's remove it!" is NOT how that saying goes.

Comment: I filed a bug: #5084145. Hope others do the same so maybe Apple will consider bringing back this useful feature in 10.14.2.